# When the content of Thickbox is bigger than browser size - no scroll bar appear in browser

Tags: jquery, popup, thickbox

How to deal with, When the content of Thickbox is bigger then browser size - no scroll bar appear in browser.
When thickbox is displaying itself bigger then browser size and it does not show scroll bars, so there is no way of getting to the last sentences display in Thickbox like Submit or Cancel Button?

I did search internet for a solution - I did not find anything that I implemented.

I did put this code in thickbox.js , but it ignored it:

```
TB_WIDTH = 750; 
TB_HEIGHT = 750;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with overflow:scroll; or overflow:auto; on parent element.